# IBM BPM - Javascript trigger delay

Tags: javascript, ibm-bpm

for those who know Javascript and IBM BPM, I need to know how to delay the execution of the trigger below, represented by the IBM BPM code this.context.trigger();.

The code is actually working, except for the delay which is not considered in my code.

Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot

```
var _this = this;

function myFunction() {
setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
_this.context.trigger();
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: i believe you are mistakenly thinking that setTimeout is a sync function, like sleep in other languages, but in javascript setTimeout is Async and calls its first parameter after a delay of 10000. read my answer for fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are mistakenly thinking that setTimeout is a sync function, like sleep in other languages, but in javascript setTimeout is Async and calls its first parameter after a delay of 10000

you are calling `myFunction` outside which calls `_this.context.trigger` immediately then once every `10000`. rewrite your function to this code in order to work.

```
function myFunction() {
   this.context.trigger();
}
setTimeout(myFunction.bind(this), 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could work

```
var _this = this;

function myFunction() {
    _this.context.trigger();
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is not a `sleep()` function.  It does not pause execution whenever it is called.  It schedules a given callback to be executed after a timeout.  The correct usage would be:

```
function myFunction(){
    // Do something
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 1000) // Call myFunction in 1000 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

In IBM BPM if you want to set sleep, then please try below code directly in the server script block.

```
java.lang.Thread.sleep(milliseconds); (or)

java.lang.Thread.currentThread().sleep(milliseconds);
```